# Call a method from Servlet (Servlet MVC) using ajax call?

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

The current jsp page was called by using the below url request:

```
device/loan
```

and when I am calling the `jQuery.get` to this url `user/xyz` instead of calling `http://http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCTest/user/xyz` it is calling

`http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCTest/device/user/xyz`

Below is my JavaScript code:

```
$('#loanedTo').blur(function () {
    console.log("Inside" + $('#loanedTo').val().length);
    if ($('#loanedTo').val().length > 1) {
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCTest/user/badgeid", { "loginId": $('#loanedTo').val() }, function (result) {
            if (result === 'no record found') {
                alert('No Record found.');
            }
            else {
                $('#xyz').val(result);
            }

        });
    }
});
```

sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

You should not put an absolute URL for the AJAX call but a relative one:

```
 $.getJSON("user/badgeid")
```